# A function which is continuous at everywhere in its domain, but diff only at one point

Tags: general-topology

Suppose a real valued function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous everywhere. Is it possible to construct $f$ that is differentiable at only one point? If possible give an example also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible. Start with a function $g$ that is contiuous everywhere and nowhere differentiable, like the [Weierstraß function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Then choose the point where you want it differentiable, say $a$, and set

$$f(x) = (x-a)\cdot g(x).$$

Then $f$ is differentiable in $a$, with $f'(a) = g(a)$, and nowhere else.

Comment: if we take a=0 then how we prove this function not differentiable at anot equal to 0

Comment: Is your question how one proves that the function isn't differentiable at any other point than $a$?

Comment: yes , this is my question.

Comment: At a point $y \neq a$, the function $h(x) = \dfrac{1}{x-a}$ is differentiable. So if $f$ were differentiable in $y$, then the function $h(x)\cdot f(x) = g(x)$ would also be differentiable in $y$. But $g$ is nowhere differentiable.